# Can i use react spring to transition from one background gradient to another?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, react-spring

I have a mesh gradient in my background, when a button is clicked a function changes the position of the colors of the gradient. How can I add some transition so the change occurs more smoothly? Is there a React spring feature I could use?
[Here is the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-machine-ikduq0?file=/src/App.js)

This is the function that changes the background

```js
function shuffleColors() {
    let colors = [
      "hsla(316,81%,62%,1)",
      "hsla(30,69%,62%,1)",
      "hsla(350,63%,61%,1)",
      "hsla(257,99%,72%,1)",
      "hsla(64,85%,68%,1)",
      "hsla(112,77%,76%,1)"
    ];
    let newArr = [];
    let copy = colors.slice(0);
    do {
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
      let item = copy[index];
      newArr.push(item);
      copy.splice(index, 1);
    } while (copy.length >= 1);

    const r = document.querySelector(":root");

    r.style.setProperty("--color1", newArr[0]);
    r.style.setProperty("--color2", newArr[1]);
    r.style.setProperty("--color3", newArr[2]);
    r.style.setProperty("--color4", newArr[3]);
    r.style.setProperty("--color5", newArr[4]);
    r.style.setProperty("--color6", newArr[5]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you've given where you're applying a background color to the `body`, you won't be able to animate this with `react-spring` because you can't wrap the `body` in the `animated` element.

I would therefore suggest you use a wrapper element & apply the background that way. Then it's simple string interpolation, here's a codesandbox illustrating the solution – https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-machine-forked-80u5rx

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It was driving me crazy because all the example uses of react-spring were too different from what I wanted to do.

Comment: if we don't mind me asking but i see you used api.start({
      background: changeColorsToGradient(...newArr)
    });
what is "api" referencing and what is that start() method? I looked it up but im not getting an answer specific to reactjs

Comment: Hi @Dani, for more information on the `api` object returned see – https://beta.react-spring.dev/docs/getting-started#reacting-to-events or https://react-spring.dev/common/imperatives-and-refs#imperative-api

If you think the answer helped you please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thank you again! Im too new on here to upvote it but i marked it as the answer to my problem, sorry i had forgotten to do that.